# Find element '0' in each rwo of CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

What I'm trying to do should be so simple,to write a program which reads a `CSV` or `txt` file line by line and finds rows which have more than one element equal to zero then highlighting these lines and saving a new version of highlighted CSV file. 
I have a `CSV` file like this:

[image]

I have no idea how to find `elements = 0` in each row of `CSV` file and how to change the color of this row. I don know if there is a way to save a copy of changed `CSV` file.

```
if self.EnableCalibration.IsChecked():
    try:
        ImportedFile = open('some.csv', 'rb')
        CSVReading= ImportedFile.read(_MAX_LUNGHEZZA_FILE)
        Lenght_CSVReading = len(CSVReading)
        csvFileArray = []
        for row in csv.reader(ImportedFile, delimiter=' '):
            csvFileArray.append(row)
            if TWO_Elements == 0: ?
               Highlight_Row? # this is not a string or python command
               csvFileArray.next() # go to the next row
            if CSVReading.split(-1): # end of csv file
                  csvSave= csv.writer(CSVReading)  #to Save            
        ImportedFile.close()        
else:
    CSVReading = None
    Lenght_CSVReading = 0
```

Comment: How do you suppose 'highlighting a line' works in a CSV file? Which, incidentally, is usually a regular plain text file.

Comment: That's why I'm asking here, its not a python command I just wanted to show I need to change the line

Comment: The problem is that there's no way to highlight a .txt (or csv for that matter) file... Python or not python.

How big is your CSV file? I'd definitely use Pandas for this unless you have a good reason not too

Comment: You mean even I can't change the color of the texts on each row? my file should be max in a range of 140*45 (row* column). `Pandas` or `numpy` or other solutions are the same for me and reach to solution just matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the variable TWO_Elements is a string, so your code:

```
if TWO_Elements == 0: ?
```

is comparing "0" == 0: ? ->FALSE

Try to cast:

```
if int(TWO_Elements) == 0:
```

Comment: two_element is an example

Comment: Pretty sure he's asking how to check if there's more than one zero in said line

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok using Pandas, I would use the following code:

First, load the csv into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(_MAX_LUNGHEZZA_FILE)
```

Here, let's take a dummy example of a datafame:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  0  1  0  5
1  2  1  4  3  5
2  5  1  4  4  3
3  2  1  0  2  5
```

Then let's create a new column, 'invalid', which will be `True` if there is more than one element in the row that has a value of zero:

```
df['invalid'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if (x == 0).sum() > 1 else False, axis=1)

>df

   A  B  C  D  E invalid
0  5  0  1  0  5    True
1  2  1  4  3  5   False
2  5  1  4  4  3   False
3  2  1  0  2  5   False
```

To decompose a bit, the apply I'm doing is basically the same as doing:

```
more_than_one_zero = (df == 0).sum(axis=1) > 1

>more_than_one_zero
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

df[more_than_one_zero, 'invalid'] = True
df[~more_than_one_zero, 'invalid'= False
```